# psql user postgres does not exist VPN

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have problem with go into psql shell.
I can't just run psql via commands like:

```
 psql
 psql -U postgres
 sudo psql
 sudo psql -U postgres
```

I can't even list databases via:

`sudo su postgres psql -l`

There is problem with users cuz I have even no user like postgres

```
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I'm not good at postgre to figure it out only by myself. I was trying a lot of solutions and finally I'm stucked here on this problem.

I tried this too:

```
createuser --superuser postgres
```

I don't even know what roles I have, and I can't check it...
And I can't use any DMBS cuz this is on vpn server.

One more important thing. In `pg_hba.conf` I've no specified any users, there is just "all" and I changed auth to "trust" for them.

One more option:
I'm not able to use initdb - command not found, but psql, postgre is alrready isntalled...

```
VPN server with:
ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Postgres 10
docker
```

Comment: What version of Postgres? What OS and version? How did you install Postgres?

Comment: sudo apt-get install | ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS | postgres 10

Comment: Where are running the commands, on the machine you are connection to via VPN server or locally?

Comment: VPN with dockers

Comment: Per instructions here [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) what happens if you do ```sudo -u postgres psql postgres``` ?

Comment: Same as before psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist

Comment: So you are connecting to a machine via VPN and on that machine Postgres is running in a Docker container, is that correct?

Comment: Yup. But I can't even restart docker with it, cuz: `driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint [docker_name] Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use`

Comment: So Postgres is running in the Docker container as 5432 is the default port for Postgres. What happens if you try ```psql -d postgres -U postgres -p 5432``` ?

Comment: `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist` Same i've really no idea what is going on here. I'm not able to start container with database cuz I get error like above with info about connection and port...

Comment: So did you setup the Docker container? On the machine you are logged into what does ```ps ax | grep postgres``` show?  At this point I would update you original question with; OS & version for the machine you are logging into via VPN,  same for the Docker container, the Docker setup and where you are running the psql commands

Comment: Here is the output of ps ax -> https://pastebin.com/pZTj4cQU
Im running these command on user in vpn, i cant get into container which includes postgres i think

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to think about this.

Comment: What does sudo ss -tulw show?

Comment: The list contains `tcp                  LISTEN                 0                      128                                             127.0.0.1:postgresql                                      0.0.0.0:*  `

Comment: I noticed that I'm not able to start container which contains database, postgres, etc. cuz -> `Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint database (id of container): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: database`

Comment: You can't start the Docker container because it is setting the port that the database listens on to 5432 on the host it is running on. That port is already being used by a Postgres server running on the Docker host. The immediate issue is this: ```psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist```. There should be a ```postgres``` role/user in the database as that is created by the Ubuntu install. Did you do the install on the host? Did you create the Docker container?

Comment: I have some scripts for building all containers, but something not working. I need to wait for someone who created it :/

Comment: If the Docker container is not running then the issue you are seeing with psql is not with Postgres in the container, but with the Postgres instance running on the host. That needs to be solved before you can go any further.

Comment: I stopped everything via docker compose down, now I'm able to start container with database. But still in this container i'm not able to get into psql -U postgres -> role "postgres" does not exist

Comment: There will be no answer to this issue until you provide complete information. So to repeat- What is OS and version for Docker host?  In Docker container?  Is there a Postgres instance running on host? If so what port is it listening on? What port is Docker Postgres running on? Are you actually running the psql command in the container or on the host against the container? How is Postgres setup in Docker container? Put answers in your question. If you don't answer all the questions there is no point in carrying on conversation.